# OroCRM 4.1: SQLSTATE[42000] Syntax error or access violation: 1064

Tags: orocrm

I got this error [SQLSTATE[42000] Syntax error or access violation: 1064](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hP0te.jpg). I am running on OroCRM 4.1, MySQL 8.0.19 and PHP 7.4.4

I did see this forum [post](https://forum.oroinc.com/orocommerce/topic/oro-3.1.17-installation-mysql-8.0.16-fails-due-to-sql-error/) but it was with OroCRM 3.1.7, so would I need to install OroCRM 3.1.7 and MySQL 5.7 or is there an updated combination that I could run where I don't run into errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure your environment meets the [OroCRM system requirements](https://doc.oroinc.com/backend/setup/system-requirements/).

The application is not compatible with MySQL 8.0 for now.